# Loss function does not decreases and accuracy gives and output of 50% on a binary softmax

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am training a deep model and the loss function does not seems to decrease. I would like to know if any of you could look at my architecture and tell what am I missing. The model does not seems to be learning anything. Many thanks!

I have already shuffled data, made the model wider and deeper. It only results in overfitting, the architecture that I am sharing does not overfits but loss function is not decreasing.

The dataset is composed of training data size (623,25) reshaped to be (623,5,5) and testing (151,25) to (151,5,5).

training labels to be (623,2) and (151,2) after one hot encoding. The model is a binary softmax classifier.

```
network = models.Sequential()
network.add(Conv1D(filters=25, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',input_shape=(25,1)))
network.add(layers.Dense(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(25,)))
network.add(Dropout(0.8))
network.add(layers.Dense(30, activation='relu', input_shape=(25,)))
network.add(Dropout(0.5))
network.add(layers.Dense(15, activation='relu', input_shape=(25,)))
network.add(Conv1D(filters=25, kernel_size=2, activation='relu',input_shape=(25,)))
network.add(MaxPooling1D())
network.add(Flatten())
network.add(layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
network.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
history=network.fit(train_x, train_y,validation_split=0.25, epochs=20000, batch_size=12,shuffle=True)
test_loss, test_acc = network.evaluate(test_x, test_y)
```

I am expecting to have an accuracy of at least 85%, maybe.

Many thanks!

Comment: This 50% of accuracy is on the test set, right? Can you tell what is the accuracy on training?

Comment: Sure thing. These are the readings that I get from training and validation. loss: 0.6534 - acc: 0.5824 - val_loss: 0.6918 - val_acc: 0.5705 This is after 4,000 epochs.

Comment: Another thought, any reason you are using Conv1d? It is a 5*5 image I believe right? why you go with 1-dimensional convolution?

Comment: I honestly don't have any reason to choose a convolution, I thought it will be useful given the dataset that I have. I am not training images, the features are reading from TCP/IP packets, classified in either a cyber attack or non-cyberattack. I thought that by reshaping the 25 features that I have into an "image" of 5 by 5, the network will learn dense correlations between different points of the "data image". Would it be a good idea to just drop the 1D convolution?

Comment: If you want to consider it as an image and make 25 features to 5*5, you are considering a kind of relations between the nearest pixel ( which I believe it is not your case) and also, you are hurting your system. and yet you use a conv1d, with a kernel size of 2, which means you do not really see the advantage of your conv1 between 5th and 6th feature, or between 5th and 7th feature and etc. Although none of these might justify your low accuracy, I highly suggest whether to use con1d and keep your 25 features as it is, or use a 5*5 and use a conv2d.

Comment: I have just revised your code. I am not sure why you have this architecture? con1d-dense-dense-dense-conv1d-dense . Is there a reason for this special architecture? Normally you use a series of convolution layers to provide a set of conv features, and then you use a dense or more to mix the features in higher dimension space and provide you a dense vector to put to a decision maker, for ex a classifier like softmax. Did you get this architecture from any state-of-the-art of DL?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I did not follow any research paper for my architecture. I was thinking of creating feature maps in between dense connected layers. So, would you advice to stack-up all dense connected layers on top of all CONV 1D? before going into the softmax classifier?

Comment: Yes, I would give it a try.  Let's go by a conv1d-conv1d-dense-softmax to see how it goes. I would add batch normalization layer after each conv1d. Also if you use conv1d, do not change the dim from 25 to 5*5. Otherwise, go with conv2d. By the way, you have a very tiny set for training a deep neural net. Any chance you enlarge it? this amount of data, you might not be able to generalize very well your data, and you might underfit, which can cause a low accuracy on both train and test.

Comment: Many thanks for the advice, I am going to follow your architecture and see what results I get. Even if it improves (which I am pretty sure it will) I am not sure if I will get satisfactory results due to my limited data. I only have 600 samples for training and 100 for testing. (aprox)

Comment: Can you do some data augmentation trick? I have no idea what your features are, but I encourage you to have a look at data augmentation techniques if any of them seem to work for you, give it a try. Good luck!